# Структура вершины по FVF коду

Tags: c, opengl, directx

Хотел распаковать 3D модель из игры FarCry 2. В ходе чтения .xbg файлов в hex-редакторе дошёл до самого сокровенного - до буфера вершин. Но понять как упакованы вершины в буфере не могу.
Есть буфер вершин и есть описание буфера.
[image: буфер вершин и описание буфера вершин]
О структуре вершины должна говорить строка FVF_CODE в описании буфера. Но не могу понять как ОНО его описывает или как по этому коду понять структуру вершины.

есть FVF_CODE: 3034 (SIZEOF = 40) И 3018 (SIZEOF = 32);
У моделей есть скелет.

FLOAT значения строк в вершине никак этому не помогают. Они выглядят не рационально.

Comment: Могу предположить, что первые три `float`-а — положение вершины (где-то далеко на оси Z), вторая тройка — координаты нормали (все три числа меньше единицы), затем (наверное) текстурные координаты и ещё что-то.